# How to set receivedDataEncoding for big5 chinese?

Tags: iphone, encoding, big5

I have a trouble in received data with chinese-big5 encoded web-page,
and I tried to get some sample code but can not find I need for big5 like below:

```
if ([encodingName isEqualToString:@"euc-jp"]) {
    receivedDataEncoding = NSJapaneseEUCSStringEncoding;
} else {
receivedDataEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding};
```

How to replace the part of "NSJapaneseEUCSStringEncoding" for big5 chinese encoding?

Thanks for answer first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [kCFStringEncodingBig5_E](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001211) constant which is available in

```
CoreFoundation/CFStringEncodingExt.h
```